# Starting a service before login and removing a user from a group

Tags: c#, windows-services

I want to create a windows service that would start before user can login. I want it to start before login so I can remove a user (windows user) from group (HomeUser to be precise), so I dont have to re-login.

So I want to:

1. Create a service that starts before user can login
2. Remove a user from group.

Any idea how this can be accomplished in C#?

**Edit**

For part-2 of question; Here the link on how you can do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupprincipal.members.aspx

Comment: Not sure if you can use the "RunOnce" registry key to do this.  I think that's similar to how windows queues files to be deleted that are in-use when maintenance runs.  Otherwise, just modify one of the other services to "depend on" your service.  hacky and risky though.

Comment: yeah, I was also thinking to do this, but I thought of asking this to do it the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How to do it:**

Use the `Windows Service` (not WCF service!) project type in Visual Studio.

Put your implementation in the `OnStart´ method. Add a projectInstaller and configure it to install the service in the`Started´ mode.

compile your project, run `installutil.exe -i´ on your projects.exe

That should install your service, and on next boot have it start.

**Why to do it?:**

Tbh, it sounds to me like something that is done once, not every boot ´removing a user from a group´. Unless someone else puts the user back in the group, its going to stay the way you set it last.. So, doing it every cold-boot sounds redundant.

Also remember, modifying security settings is a pretty high privilege. Not many accounts are allowed to do this. Make sure your service is installed with an identity which has permission to these levels.

Comment: The removing user part; I am making this service so I don't have to remove the user every time. I don't know why, but windows put the user back in group when I restart.

Comment: Just a weird thought, but it there any way to prevent windows from putting that user in the group in the first place? Or are you bound to a domain controller who does this? I think it would be better to prevent this issue from occuring than trying to reverse it after the fact. Is there more info you can/are allowed to/are willing to give about the user account? Sounds to me like there has to be a solution in the ´homeuser´ direction.

Comment: Just finished up reading some on the HomeUsers group. At first glance it seems about networking with Samba and related topics. But what hit me was the mentioning of GPO´s. This would be your ´correct´ way to ´execute functionality before a user is allowed to log on´. At least, thats what you can use it for in domains envs. If this is true, than i would suggest setting up a GPO who does your ´remove user from group´. check out
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766208%28WS.10%29.aspx (vista version). Maybe your `insert user into HomeUsers group´ is a GPO by itself!

Answer (score 1):

Starting at boot is something *any* service can do, as long as it doesn't need any GUI to operate. It is one of the startup options for a service. Just set it up that way, and you are good to go.

As for making a C# program a service, I'm not too sure. Perhaps they have something, but I'd imagine you'd need to at least wrap it in some unmanaged C++ to interface with the Windows Service API.

Comment: I do know how to create a service, but didn't had any idea how to start it before user login.

Comment: Good. It *kinda* looked that way from the way your question was asked, but I wasn't sure.